How to prevent Swagger from crashing when receiving huge responses?
Swagger continually crashes when trying out endpoints with large responses.
We have tried disabling syntax highlighting to reduce filesize but still ran into issue.
Spring configs to remove syntax highlight:
springdoc:
    swagger-ui:
        syntaxHighlight:
            activated: false

We are using SpringBoot 3.
Are there any known ways to have swagger only return file as a downloadable without preview or allow larger sized api responses?

what are the logs when swagger crashes?

It seems springdoc has only syntaxHighlight config for speeding up ui, as it's not helping i can suggest:

Write custom OpenApiCustomizer bean, override customise(OpenAPI openApi) method, like this

@Override
public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
    openApi.getComponents().getSchemas().forEach((s, schema) -> {
                // check example length
                if (schema.getExample().toString().length() > 1000L) {
                    schema.setExample("download example here: http://example.com");
                }
            });


If the problem is only in UI and not in swagger json/yaml file, you can customize ui css and js, example is here
https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/737
It's somewhat hacky, but can help

Write an issue on https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi, suggest solution, or write one yourself


